# Where is lock screen image saved on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, images, lock-screen

I need to format my disks and reinstall windows but I want to keep image i used for lock screen. I have no idea what i typed to google so maybe this image is somewhere on my pc. I deleted original one

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: duplicates: https://superuser.com/questions/1126403/what-is-the-location-of-lock-screen-images-on-windows-10?rq=1 and https://superuser.com/questions/1071872/where-is-my-lock-screen-image-file and https://superuser.com/questions/1376513/retrieve-custom-windows-10-lock-screen-image?rq=1

Comment: There are many answers across those links.